# Can I set up global babel presets?

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs

Instead of using a per project babel configuration, can I put a .babelrc file in my home folder? Or is there another way to install and run babel globally?

Comment: Minus 1. You know that old saying, "There's no such thing as a stupid question?" Well, on Stackoverflow there most definitely are : )

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is definitely not recommended. You'll have no way to manage what versions of things are used where. It might work, but it'll be tons of pain in the long run. If your config is complex, you can make your own preset to centralize the combination of things you use, then install that single preset in every project you need it in.

Comment: But wouldn't this make your project large? I mean wouldn't it?